# VBA macro to count all unhidden rows in a user-given range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that counts all unhidden rows in a user given range. Below is the specific snippet that is not working: assume a textbox in previous code has already collected the user input and stored in the storedValue variable.

When I run this code, the variable count is always equal to zero despite there being rows hidden.

Can anyone advise?

```
    'Apply the autofilter that hides some rows
    With BOM.Worksheets("BOM").UsedRange
       .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="4"
    End With
    
    'Count number of visible rows until user-inputted value (storedValue: "A1:A99" example)
    Dim count As Long
    Dim sum1 As Variant

    sum1 = ActiveSheet.range(storedValue).Rows.count
    
    If range(storedValue).EntireRow.Hidden Then
        count = count + 1
    End If
    
    wkb.Worksheets(1).range("F2") = count
    sum1 = sum1 - count
    wkb.Worksheets(1).range("F3") = sum1
```

**edit: new code (and preceding code) below:

```
Sub KPI_Data()
        
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim BOM As Workbook
'
    'Adding New Workbook
   Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
  ' variable for the bom workbook
    Set BOM = ThisWorkbook

    'Receiving input from the user of the row number of the last mech line item
    'input from user is stored in wkb.Worksheets(1) ---> A1
    Dim userInput As Variant
    userInput = InputBox("Type the row number of the last mechanical line item")

    'Prints this on data excel sheet for reference
    wkb.Worksheets(1).range("A1").Value = "Last Mech line item row number"
    wkb.Worksheets(1).range("B1") = userInput
    
    Dim storedValue As Variant
    storedValue = "A1:A" + userInput
    
    'Count number of visible rows until user-inputted value (the last mech line item row number)
  
    Dim count As Long
    Dim sum1 As Variant
    count = 0
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
 
    sum1 = ActiveSheet.range(storedValue).Rows.count
 
    While i <= userInput
        If ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Hidden = True Then
            count = count + 1
            MsgBox "it works"
        End If
        i = i + 1
       
    Wend
    
    wkb.Worksheets(1).range("F2") = count
    sum1 = sum1 - count
    wkb.Worksheets(1).range("F3") = sum1


 End Sub
```

I'm finding that with the while loop, it still is not entering the if statement to count the hidden rows

EDIT 2
RESOLVED! the issue was in the while loop, it needed to reference the workbook title and sheet not ThisWorksheet:

```
    While i <= userInput
        If BOM.Worksheets("BOM").Rows(i).Hidden = True Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
       
    Wend
    
    wkb.Worksheets(1).range("F2") = count
    sum1 = sum1 - (count + 4)
    wkb.Worksheets(1).range("F3") = sum1
```

Comment: `If range(storedValue).EntireRow.Hidden Then`: probably needs a loop.

Comment: @BigBen Is the if loop not sufficient? Like, does it cycle through every row in the given range? I'm new to VBA coding here

Comment: An `If` statement is completely different from a loop.

Comment: Or you can use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and avoid a loop.

Comment: Is this happening in one worksheet? You're using `BOM.Worksheets("BOM")`, `ActiveSheet` and no reference. There is a difference between filtered not visible rows and hidden rows. Try to describe what `count` and `sum1` represent. Is `.range(storedValue)` actually `BOM.Worksheets("BOM").UsedRange.Columns("A")`? If you're not sure, try to use the `Address` property e.g. `Debug.Print BOM.Worksheets("BOM").UsedRange.Columns("A").Address` and similarly for `storedValue` and compare the results. You should probably add more of the preceding code.

Comment: @VBasic2008 updated in post. can you advise?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Is there a way to get values to enter the if statement if they are "filtered not visible rows" instead of hidden rows? I think that might be the problem

Comment: @VBasic2008 Resolved! It was a worksheet title issue bc I was interacting with two sheets. Thank you :)))